# Drupal 7 view Global text write condition inside

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I was new to drupal 7 but I used the Drupal , my question is I have a view with some fields in a hidden state and I use Global text to render them using some HTML.

So, the problem is I've a field called middle name and this is wrapped inside a html tag,

for eg:

```
<h1>[field_middle_name]</h1>
```

What I need is to hide the  tag if there is no middle name,

I know in D8 I can use twig to write condtions, but I dont know how to achieve this in D7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can just remove the `<h1></h1>` wrapper and make it part of the inner HTML, how do you render the content from `field_middle_name` ?

Comment: Add your h1 tag inside field_middle_name under "rewrite result" field section, now If your field will be empty your tag in global text also will be hidden. Also, check options "hide the field if empty".

Answer (score -1):

Drupal 7 templates are actually PHP files so you can use PHP for adding conditions, loops and all other actions.